If all matter is in a state of vibration what is the fundamental source of this vibration. In other words, how is this vibration state initiated
If all matter is in a state of vibration what is the fundamental source of this vibration. In other words, how is this vibration state initiated in all manifestations of matter?
Even at absolute zero temperature, vibrations still exist at the atomic or subatomic level.
If those atomic level vibrations were able to be quelled to zero, would matter cease to exist?


how is this vibration state initiated

It is not something that is initiated. There is no state of matter without vibration. “Initiation” of vibration implies that there was first a non-vibratory state to which something had to happen to change it into a vibratory state.
That isn’t the case. There simply is no such state. The lowest energy state has vibration, as do all higher energy states.

Vibration implies that an energy source is at play to drive the vibration state. Can it, also, be said that matter cannot exist without some level of vibration?

Vibration does imply that there is energy, but I don't think that it implies that there is "an energy source ... to drive the vibration state" (emphasis added). We know that there is a lot of energy in mass, so no source is needed besides the matter itself, and there is no state of matter without vibration so there is no need to drive the vibration.
